# How to check If a column contains a specific word and make a new column (1 or 0)

Tags: pandas

My dataframe is like this:

```
`id` `text`
1     Hello world how are you
2     Hello people I am fine
3     Good Morning
4     Good Evening
```

I want to check if the column contains "Good". If it does, I want to create a new column containing 1 like this:

```
`id` `text`                         c1
1     Hello world how are you       0
2     Hello people I am fine        0 
3     Good Morning                  1
4     Good Evening                  1
```

Comment: `df['c1']=df.text.str.contains('Good',na=False).astype(int)`

Comment: is it case sensitive? 'Good', 'good, 'gOOD' etc will be same or not? Thank you. Just asking

Comment: for case insensitive use `case=False` inside `str.contains()`

Answer (score 3):

I slightly change your input which contain some word have partial of them match 'Good', in that case `str.contains('Good')` will failed

```
df
Out[120]: 
   id                    text  
0   1       Goodbye my friend         
1   2  Hello people I am fine         
2   3            Good Morning         
3   4            Good Evening     

df.text.str.contains(r'\bGood\b') # if needed add na=False
Out[121]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: text, dtype: bool
```

---

For anky_91 answer

```
df.text.str.contains('Good',na=False)
Out[122]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: text, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Is there any difference between :::   `df.text.str.contains(r'\bGood\b')`  andd `df.text.str.contains(' Good ')`

Comment: @johndoe `\bGood\b` only select the words like Good , not GoodBye